# Python WMI returns empty answer for request under SheduledTask execution

Tags: python, windows, wmi

I have a code which is successfully works in common situation when i run script after login

```
rval = 0  # Default: Check passes.
wmi_o = wmi.WMI('server')
#wmi_o = wmi.WMI('server',user='domain\DMAdminuser', password='pwd')
wql = ("SELECT * FROM Win32_NTLogEvent WHERE Logfile='Application' AND SourceName='SQLISPackage110' and (EventCode='12289' or EventCode='12291')")
wql_r = wmi_o.query(wql)
if len(wql_r):
    rval = -1  # Check fails.
```

But i have SheduledTask with Domain Admin
privileges, to execute this script, and it's return empty answer

I tried

```
wmi_o = wmi.WMI('server',user='domain\DMAdminuser', password='pwd')
```

its works well under usual login, but not working under SheduledTask execution.

Requests was made from Windows10(22H2) or Server 2022(21H2) to Server 2012R2

So question is - how make it work?